# How to pass input values to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Okay, I'm new to Ajax. My problem is that I'm not sure how to retrieve data which is in the `<input>` tag and send it to Ajax. I have tried searching on the internet, but most of the solutions are using jQuery Ajax, which is what I'm not looking for at the moment.

Here is my code.

I want to save this value so that my Ajax can read it...

```
<input id="IDValue" name="IDValue" value="<?php echo $row['exist']?>" >
```

This is my Ajax script...

```
 function message(){
    var ID=$(".IDValue").val();
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            }
                        };
             xmlhttp.open("POST","retrieveMsg.php?q=" +ID,true);
             xmlhttp.send();
               }
```

Please help me, guys. The reason I am doing this method is because (My previous post) [Send input value to php using ajax with result printed to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805611/retrieving-data-from-database-and-displaying-it-by-using-ajax)

Comment: Well, but you are trying to use jQuery to get the input field value. You are putting a dot infront of it but you need a hash. (var ID = $("#IDValue").val();)

Comment: `var ID = document.querySelector('#IDValue').value;` is the non-jquery equivalent.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: @akhilp2255 i dont thnk its a duplicate....That page was using jquery which was not what i was looking for.

Comment: @Shilly Thanks sir, that worked.Tested .

Comment: @kiwiJuicer, noted ! :D thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace it

```
 var ID=$(".IDValue").val();
```

With

```
 var ID = document.getElementById("IDValie").value;
```

Comment: Thanks ! but what if it is  `<input class="IDValue" name="IDValue" value="<?php echo $row['exist']?>" >` (if it is class ?)

Comment: For class use this document.getElementsByClassName('IDValue');

Comment: HAHA yesss ! I just tested and that solved my problem ! Thankss !

Answer (score 0):

i am confused about your $row['exist'] returns value or not and what html control you used for id="txtHint". here i have provided demo which same as your code in some way...try and have an idea and make changes as per your requirement...

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="IDValue" name="IDValue" value="<?php echo 'hello';?>"  >
        <textarea id="txtHint"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Click" onClick="message()"/>
    <script>
        function message(){
    var ID=$("#IDValue").val();
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            }
                        };
             xmlhttp.open("POST","login.php?q=" +ID,true);
             xmlhttp.send();
               }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```